# Google OAuth2 - tokens, on-line, offline, adding scopes incrementally

Tags: access-token, google-contacts-api, offline-mode

Trying to organize this question into something clear. We are integrating Google for Work into our application, to use login, Google+, and eventually Contacts, Calendar, etc. As is recommended by Google and everything I have read, we are going to use incremental access, only adding scopes when they are needed. We are a PHP shop.

But, we will also be needing offline access, as our Contacts (and eventually Calendar) access will be synchronizing with our internal database.

We currently capture the Access and Refresh Tokens when doing the initial link, and store them locally, so that we can re-authorize at any time by using the Refresh token whenever the Access token expires. This is working correctly.

Questions:
a) when adding the incremental scopes for Contacts, the documentation says we need to call the `gapi.auth.signIn()` function in the page javascript with the new scopes. This is working on the page where we are allowing folks to manage settings. In the original login function callback, I save the Access Token and scopes with an Ajax call that uses the access code passed into the callback, and calls the `Google_Client authenticate()` function to get the access code and scopes... but at that point, the information I get back does not have the new scopes. Why? Do I have to re-extend the scopes every time the page is drawn?

b) since we are going to have a batch process do the contact synchronization, do I need to get an entirely different access token with `access_type=offline`, or can I use the current access token (properly extended with the new scopes). Can an off-line access token be used for on-line access as well as off-line? Or vice-versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your questions:

a) have you used the parameter "include_granted_scopes"? as mentioned here: 
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#incrementalAuth

b) When you request an offline access token, the response contains the access token and refresh token. so you can refresh the access token after it expires without having the user grant the permissions again.

online access token and offline access token work for the same.

the difference between both its the capability to refresh the access token when it expires without involving the user. Which is the functionality for the offline type.
The online access token doesn't mean that it works for your client-side authentication (done in the browser) and the offline works for the server-side.

You mentioned that you can get an access token, refresh token and authorization code from the client-side of your app. You could send that information to your server and make api calls from there, although this is not a good practice.

I would suggest that you do the OAuth Flow in the server side and from there manage the users information and API calls.

Here you can find the documentation on both [Web server](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) applications and [Client Side](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent) applications.

Hope it's clearer.

Comment: Many thanks, Gerardo. You did indeed answer the biggest question - whether the offline and online tokens work the same. I have things working much better. Now if only I can get the etags to behave...

Comment: if this solution was helpful, please accept it as answer.

Comment: Ummm... how? Gotta say, the interface on StackOverflow is somewhat... stilted.